# i want to take the data from html page and store in a file as json data in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

The following is my html code i want to read the file ans store the data in a file using node.js

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>The Page Returned by Making Http Call to Node.js</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table, td {
          border:double;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Product Information Page</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>

            <td>Product Id:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button"  id = "textFieldId" value="Save"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

The following is my Node.js code i want to write  the user input text fields to my filesystem

```
app.get('/list_user', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join((__dirname + '/AppPages/MyPage.html')))
  let inputContent = res.body;
  console.log(inputContent);
  JSON.stringify(inputContent);
  fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/AppPages/data.json',inputContent,function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('saved')
  })
```

I am getting in data.json as undefined

Comment: You have many issues here. There is no form shown to send data. There is no body on a GET request and any body is part of req not res. Then you are using JSON.stringify incorrectly. Also not clear if you are using body parser. Study some form tutorials

Comment: Thanks 

can you please suggest any tutoriel which reads the data from html form and store in file format

Comment: before you even worry about writing data to file make sure you understand how using and reading form data works first and difference between GET and POST with regard to how data is read from request server side

Answer (score 0):

There is no place in your code you initialized the data object however looks like you can inputcontent instead

Answer (score 0):

1. Should have get and post page.
2. Change table to form and set action to your post page.
3. On your post routes you can access the data sending via req.body its an oject
   you have to parse this as string in order for you to write it to a file, Use JSON.stringyfy method, Take note you have to install body-parser and use it on your
   express.